# What are they burning and why are they doing it?

Tags: plot-explanation, love-death-and-robots

In "The Drowned Giant", an episode of season 2 of ***Love, Death & Robots***, what are they burning after the humans have dismembered the body of this dead giant?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not mentioned explicitly in the episode what is in those pots. Towards the end of this episode we see that the people find uses for various of the giant's body parts. There is also a comparison made to whales. This gave me an idea:

What we see looks like giant cooking pots that could contain fatty tissue (or Adipose tissue) from the giant which is boiled to produce oil, basically the same procedure like boiling whale blubber in the old days. This is of course speculation but it fits well, I think. Another possibility is boiling various parts (tendons, ligaments, bones) to produce gelatin.

Comment: thanks, for a second, I was thinking the humans were cooking the meat for food. That would be a really dark theme.